# I am working with PHP and have an Array that looks something like this :

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, array-merge

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  class_name:10:date:2014-03-08:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Maths:exam_details:Extra comments:
    [1] =>  class_name:10:date:2014-03-07:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Eng:exam_details:Extra comments:
    [2] =>  class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:
    [3] =>  class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:
    [4] =>  class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:
    [5] =>  class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:
)
```

As you can see, there are some start_time and finish_time in  array I would like to divide element using  explode function with deliminators ":" but explode divide value of start_time and finish time also .is it possible to explode value using same deliminators

Comment: You need to apply a regex to this.

Comment: use preg_match: http://it1.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 2):

This is a raw sketch of what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$input = array (
  0 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-08:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Maths:exam_details:Extra comments:',
  1 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-07:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Eng:exam_details:Extra comments:',
  2 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:',
  3 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:',
  4 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:',
  5 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:'
);

$tokens = array();
foreach ($input as $key=>$line) {
  echo sprintf("line %s:\n", $key);
  preg_match('/class_name:([0-9]+):date:([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}):start_time:([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):finish_time:([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):subject:([^:]+)/',
             $line , $tokens);
  var_dump($tokens);
  echo "\n\n";
};

?>
```

Probably the `regular expression` has to be adapted according to the real content of the array. It currently does not capture the tokens in the end of each line currently, since the syntax is not clear from your question. But you should get the basic idea.

The output of this is (shortened):

```
line 0:
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(78) "class_name:10:date:2014-03 08:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Maths"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "10"
  [2] =>
  string(10) "2014-03-08"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "10:15"
  [4] =>
  string(5) "12:15"
  [5] =>
  string(5) "Maths"
}


line 1:
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(76) "class_name:10:date:2014-03-07:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Eng"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "10"
  [2] =>
  string(10) "2014-03-07"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "10:15"
  [4] =>
  string(5) "12:15"
  [5] =>
  string(3) "Eng"
}


[...]
```

The output is currently rendered for cli usage of php which makes developing of such things easier. If you want to test it in a browser then you have to replace the `\n` linebreaks by `<br>` tags and the like.

Comment: Not that important, but don't forget to declare `$tokens` as an array.. PHP 4 doesn't let me go on if it's not declared before preg_match :P

Comment: @briosheje You are right that $token is not declared, though that is actually not required in PHP. I do not see any feature in PHP preventing execution. The most you would get is a warning, though I don't really see why... Could you specify the error message please?

Comment: @arkascha: "undefined variable: $tokens" ;) in any case it does happen just with few PHP versions, from 4.2.1 above, from what I've seen, it is actually considered a "notice" error that, sometimes, is even suppressed :)

Comment: @briosheje Ok, but that is a _warning_, not an _error_, so it certainly does _not_ keep you from "going on". I do agree however that is it is cleaner to declare the variable, so I adjusted the code according to that. Thanks!

Comment: @arkascha: it actually popups as an error with my PHP 4.1.something :P. In any case, that was just to point that out in case someone (eventually you) may encounter that problem; that was not meant to complain anything about the code above :)

Comment: @briosheje Sure, as said: thanks for pointing that out! But may I ask what setup you use so that PHP can "popup" an error? Also, again you call this an "error" which confuses me. Now is this an "error" you get or a "warning"? If it's really an error for you, what setup? Because PHP certainly does _not_ throw an error for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic method in your case.

You must o it yourself.

This is an idea of what you can do

```
$keys = array('class_name','date','start_time','finish_time','subject','exam_details');

// for each line of your table
$parseData = retreiveData($keys, $stringData);

function retreiveData($keys, $stringData)
{   
    $results = array();
    $returnValue = preg_split('/('.implode('|', $keys).')/', $stringData, -1);
    for ($i =0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
        $results[$i] = rtrim(ltrim($returnValue[$i],':'),':');
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual Array:

```
$data =Array
(
    0 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-08:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Maths:exam_details:Extra comments:',
    1 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-07:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Eng:exam_details:Extra comments:',
    2 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:',
    3 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:',
    4 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:',
    5 =>  'class_name:10:date:2014-03-06:start_time:10:15:finish_time:12:15:subject:Science:exam_details:Extra comments:'
);
```

// Using for each loop iterate the array

```
foreach($data as $dt=>$val){
use explode function and create an array

$datas= explode(':',$val);
```

// Create an array according to your need

```
$new_array[] = array($datas[0],$datas[1],$datas[2].':'.$datas[3],$datas[4].':'.$datas[5].':'.$datas[6],$datas[7].':'.$datas[8].':'.$datas[9],$datas[10],$datas[11],$datas[12],$datas[13]);
```

---

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```

will give you desired result